# How to prove the above expectation inequality?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

If $\mathbb{E}[|X|^k]<\infty$ then for $0<j<k$, $\mathbb{E}[|X|^j]<\infty$, and furthermore $\mathbb{E}[|X|^j]\leq(\mathbb{E}[|X|^k])^{j/k}.$

How to prove the above expectation inequality?

Comment: Actual probability notation is really horrendous and it doesn't add any intuitive understanding.

Comment: @Felix Marin: The notation is just the standard one.

Comment: @FelixMarin Is this comment making you feel any better? Because apart from that...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know it's pretty standard. You're always doing a nice job. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second inequality, that trivially implies the first one, is a consequence of [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality):
$$\varphi(\mathbb{E}[Z])\leq \mathbb{E}[\varphi(Z)]$$
by choosing $\varphi(x)=x^{k/j}$ and $Z=|X|^{j}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple proof of the first inequality, assuming we express $\mathbb{E}$ as a Stieltjes integral with respect to the cumulative distribution function $F$.

If $|x| \geq 1$ and $0 < j < k$, then $|x|^j \leq |x|^k$. Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|X|^j] &= \int_\mathbb{R} |x|^j dF\\
&= \int_{-1}^{1}|x|^j dF + \int_{|x| > 1}|x|^j dF \\
&\leq \int_{-1}^{1}1 dF + \int_{|x| > 1}|x|^k dF \\
&\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}1 dF + \int_{\mathbb{R}}|x|^k dF \\
&= 1 + \int_{\mathbb{R}}|x|^k dF \\
&< \infty
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 for a bare-bones solution.